# Interaction between definition of convergence and definition of a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a thinking problem regarding definition of convergence and definition of a limit.

Assume we have some sequence $ a_{n}$

the definition of convergent sequence: $ (\forall \epsilon > 0)( \exists n_{\epsilon}\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n>n_{\epsilon})(|a_{n} - L|< \epsilon) $

From that definition we say that that sequence is going closer and closer to L (L is the limit). If limit exists our sequence is convergent.

I am confused about having the definition of a limit that says:

a is limit point

$ (\forall \epsilon > 0)( \exists \delta>0)(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})(0<|n-a|<\delta)\Rightarrow(|a_{n}-L|<\epsilon))$

I am confused about having $\delta$ in definition of limit and how is interacting with definition of convergence. What is the meaning of some number $\delta$ and why is it important in definition of limit?

Didn't we already had the definition of limit as part of definition of convergents?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you sure you've got the definition for limit point correct?  I've never seen that definition and it, frankly, doesn't make any sense.  I do have an answer as to why some definitions use a large n as a "tipping point" for higher terms in a sequence and other definitions use a small delta as a "tipping point" for points that are close together. But I want to explain it in terms of your definitions.  But your definitions are off.

Answer (score 0):

Difference is that in the definition of the limit you do not have natural number $n$. You have some real number x, and you do not have sequence $a_{n}$ but some function of x, $f(x)$ and it means that as x is nearing $a$ then $f(x)$ is nearing some L.